# why does printf space padding only allows one space?

Tags: php, printf, padding

This is my code:

```
<?php
$str1 = "Hello";
printf("[%99s]",$str1);
?>
```

I expect it to output 94 spaces as padding to fulfill the min length.  Why does it only output 1 space to the right of the string?

Comment: I get this from your code: `[<94 spaces>Hello]`. Minus one.

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're outputting to a web page, HTML doesn't see spaces (if you check the source code, the 94 spaces are probably present). You'd have to pad with `'&nbsp;'`.

Try this instead:

```
echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', sprintf("[%-99s]\n", $str1));
```

Comment: I should clarify, my problem isn't the alignment.  the output I get is
[ hello], where I expect [  ...many spaces here...                             hello]

Comment: If you're outputting to a web page, HTML doesn't see spaces (if you check the source code, the 94 spaces are probably present). You'd have to use `sprintf` then convert ` ` to `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Browsers eliminate multiple spaces unless encoded.  Try using &nbsp; instead of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds the correct amount of spaces. Your problem most probably is just that you look at the representation of it in the browser instead of the source code. In HTML more than one space will be combined to just one.

Either view your output in the browser source code or use this:

```
<pre>
<?php
$str1 = "Hello";
printf("[%99s]",$str1);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: i see, why is this a practical thing for the browser to do if it is a valid php command?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. HTML code is often separated over several lines, uses indentation, and so on. All that whitespace would not be wanted in the representation of the browser. HTML offers `&nbsp;` and `<br />` for such things.